# PoDoFo polish characters & PdfContentsTokenizer error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, polish, podofo

**1.**

How to get polish characters **from** pdf file? Can I somehow tell

```
PdfVariant::getString()
```

it will process polish characters?
Becouse I get  `\200`instead of `ł` for example and the funny thing is thats only when `ł` occures as first "nonbase" character. So if the pdf file begins with `aaaałęąaaaa`, the `ł` is coded like `\200`, the `ę` like `\201` and `ą` like `\202`  **but**  if pdf file begins with `aaaaąęłaaaa`, the `ł` is coded like `\202`, the `ę` like `\201` and `ą` like `\200`
How can i get this characters in any system?

**2.**

When i'm trying to extract text from pdf file, I do something like this:

```
string input_name = "example.pdf";
PdfMemDocument pdf(input_name.c_str());
    for (int pn = 0; pn < pdf.GetPageCount(); ++pn) {
        PdfPage* page = pdf.GetPage(pn); 
        PdfContentsTokenizer tok(page);
        const char* token = nullptr;
        PdfVariant var;
        EPdfContentsType type;
        while (tok.ReadNext(type, token, var)) {
           //etc.
```

But I got problem with `PdfContentsTokenizer tok(page);` It doesn't work properly. For some pdf files it goes smoothly and for the other it throws `Access violation reading location` error in `inffas32.asm` file, `669` line:

```
L_get_length_code_mmx:
pand mm4,mm0
movd eax,mm4
movq mm4,mm3
mov  eax, [ebx+eax*4]//this is the error line
```

Btw, I noticed not every pdf file is coded in the same way. For example, using podofobrowser I couldn't see `Hello World!` text from the official podofo helloworld example. And for the others pdf files podofobrowser showed text in different ways or didn't show it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ad 1.**  [The link to patch files](https://sourceforge.net/p/podofo/mailman/message/35654027/) 
which allows to extraxt polish text from pdf using [TextExtractor.](https://github.com/mekentosj/podofo/tree/master/tools/podofotxtextract)

This is the most important line when it comes to extract non-unicode text from pdf:

```
PdfString unicode = pCurFont->GetEncoding()->ConvertToUnicode( rString, pCurFont );
```

**Ad 2.** The problem was zlib library which was built wrong. I rebuit it, rebuilt podofo and the problem is gone.

Comment: Revised patches were posted here: https://sourceforge.net/p/podofo/mailman/message/35654027/

Comment: I tried TextExtractor. It started work for `ł` but it doesn't work for `ś` and `ć`

Comment: 18C, just check font you are using to display text got polish chars :)